# Monitor occasionally goes black and then comes back on again

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I've had a problem since moving to a windows 10 laptop. Every so often, one of my two connected monitors will go black momentarily and then come back on again.

Windows claims the latest drivers are installed for all my display adaptors.

Even if the driver was out of date, it seems odd that it would only affect one as they're both the same make and model.

`sfc /scannow` runs clean, as does `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`

Any idea what else it could be or anything I could try?

Answer (score 1):

There is a known problem with Intel on-board graphics cards. Intel fixes this, but insists that you use the drivers from your manufacturer. Your manufacturer might not have yet published new drivers which will cause Windows to say that you are up-to-date.

The solution is to find out what your graphics card is by going to the device manager, and go to the manufacturer's website. So in case of Intel, seach for the Intel drivers at intel.com.

When you get to choose to download it, make sure you download the .zip package, not the .exe package.

The .exe package comes with an installer which will tell you that you need to use the drivers from your manufacturer. We do not want this.

Once you have the .zip file, extract the content to a location on your harddrive that you can find later. Go to Device Manager, right-click the graphicscard and choose update drivers. Then select: I have a disk. Browse to the folder you extracted the content of the .zip file, and install these drivers.

The problem should instantly go away, but if they persist, reboot once.

If this does not fix it, then it is likely a problem with the display or the cable. You can swap the cables of the monitors to see if the problem moves to the other monitor to narrow it down. If swapping the cables does nothing, hook up that possible defective monitor to a different computer. It should now have the same symptoms on that other computer. If it indeed has this, the monitor is defective.