# 2nd monitor at a random interval goes black for maybe less then a second and then comes back again

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have a desktop computer with 2 monitors connected on on-board VGA and HDMI. The 1st monitor is connected via VGA to VGA port while the 2nd monitor is connected via VGA to HDMI connector to the HDMI port. The issue is that the 2nd monitor at a random interval goes black for maybe less then a second and then comes back again. I have been using both the monitors for past 5 years. Both the monitors used to work perfectly. This started happening since November 2021.

Here's what I have already tried:

1. I have connected the 1st monitor to the HDMI port using VGA to HDMI connector and the second monitor I have connected using VGA to VGA port.
2. I have updated the Intel (R) HD Graphics 530 driver of the display adaptor to the latest version and all other drivers to their latest version
3. Updated Windows 10 to the latest version
4. Replace the VGA cable for both the monitors
5. Check the Refresh rate for both the monitors and ensure it's 60 Hz
6. Format and reloaded Windows 10 and update drivers
7. Switch from VGA to HDMI connector to DVI cable
8. I have unplugged the 1st monitor cable from the VGA port and only the 2nd monitor was in-use and the issue didn't appear
9. I use the 2nd monitor as a external monitor for my laptop and it works great using VGA to HDMI connector to the HDMI port
10. I tried the solution provided on this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1511076/monitor-occasionally-goes-black-and-then-comes-back-on-again) but still no luck

No matter what I do it's always the 2nd monitor causing the issue. The monitor isn't bad it just something is wrong somewhere on my desktop computer that making it cause this issue.

I have prepared a video on how the issue looks like. Here's the link for the video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I06hhN0OsMIo7jmoUjWvhl3poxI4o1P3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Those old monitors connected via VGA are very sensitive regarding the frequency of the transmitted images. If you can try to change the display refresh speed. My guess would be that your monitor is limited to a refresh rate of 60Hz+. By default the converter generates a signal with exactly 60Hz but sometimes the frequency drops to 59.99HZ and then the screen goes black. IMHO if both monitors have a digital input you should use it. Better buy a cheap graphic card with two digital outputs than use VGA. VGA + LCD was never a good solution try to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your system might not have enough resources to use both video outputs at the same time.

You don't mention what motherboard (or brand-name PC model) you're using. In many cases, there is a BIOS setting that allows you to devote more system RAM for video use. If you're lucky, your system might offer a way to set more memory while in Windows.

Intel mainly produces integrated video cards that share RAM, as opposed to a discrete video card (from makers such as Nvidia or AMD) that uses its own separate memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been using both the monitors for past 5 years. Both the monitors used to work perfectly. This started happening since November 2021.